# Is there vector space $\mathbb R $ over $\mathbb R $ with dimension $m\neq1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

> I am searching a new scalar product that with this scalar product the vector space $\mathbb R $over $\mathbb R $ with ordinary vector sum has dimension $m$ , which $m$ is any arbitrary natural number.

hint: scalar product over $R-module M$ ( $R-vector space M$ ) is a two variable function like $$f:\ R\times M \rightarrow M$$ such that

1. $f(r_1+r_2,m)=f(r_1,m)+f(r_2,m)$
2. $f(r,m_1+m_2)=f(r,m_1)+f(r,m_2)$
3. $f(r_1,f(r_2,m))=f(r_1r_2,m)$

for simplicity we write $f(r,m)=r*m$

I have tried it , but with no result. I even don't know how to start to solve problem.

thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that such a scalar product would necessarily need to agree with normal multiplication for the scalar product by an integer, i.e. $n\cdot x$ where $\cdot$ is the scalar multiplication and $n$ an integer would need to be the multiplication $nx$.

Comment: @Hayden usually a "scalar" product means an inner-product, not a scalar action by the coefficient field.

Comment: @AdamHughes yes, but then the question would make  less sense (and the mention of "ordinary sum" rather suggest that the first comment got the intent right).

Comment: @AdamHughes echoing quid, I went with what made the most sense with the question, since an inner product does not have anything to do with dimension

Comment: @Hayden I disagree a little, you can talk about an inner product as a linear form, so that it makes sense to talk about relations to sums and similarly the exact form of an inner product will depend on the dimension. I also don't see how the scalar action has any *more* to do with dimension than inner product. I mean, really I think the question needs either **severe** editing or deletion and that your response isn't *unreasonable*, but I don't think the balance of probability is on one interpretation over the other given the phrasing.

Comment: Check out the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Comment: @Nate: I don't think this question fits the AC tag. It's true, the axiom of choice is essential for showing this result, but the discussion is not about its necessity.

Comment: @Asaf: It seemed to me that, since this question turns out to be about a counterintuitive consequence of AC, it was likely to be of interest to people interested in AC. Hence the tag. But if it seems inappropriate to you, feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb R $ over $\mathbb Q$ is a vector space with dimension $2^{\mathbb N}$. and also $\mathbb R^n $ over $\mathbb Q$ is a vector space with dimension $2^{\mathbb N}$. So the additive group of $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic with additive group of $\mathbb R^n$. for example consider $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be such isomorphism , now define new scalar product as follow: $$q*r=f^{-1}(q . f(r))$$  which $q,r\in\mathbb R$ and $q . f(r)$ means ordinary scalar product of   $\mathbb R^n$ .

now because $$f(q*r)=q . f(r)$$
so linear space $\mathbb R $ over $\mathbb R$ with new scalar product is linear isomorphic with space $\mathbb R^n $ over $\mathbb R$ so $\dim_\mathbb R\mathbb R$ with new scalar product is the same as $\dim_\mathbb R\mathbb R^n=n$.

Comment: It should, perhaps, be mentioned that the use of the axiom of choice here is essential.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: yes, for having basis